# How to check if a date is between two dates mysql?

Tags: mysql, date-formatting, date-range

I'm querying dates from a mysql database. When I try to select only the dates between a certain from and to date, I'm not getting the expected results back.

My query:

```
select * from tbl_billing where date BETWEEN '09-02-2017' and '10-02-2017'
```

My output:

```
09-02-2017
10-02-2017
10-01-2017
09-01-2017
09-01-2017
```

My desired result:

```
09-02-2017
10-02-2017
```

Comment: what is your type of date field in mysql table?

Comment: `'dd-mm-yyyy'` is not a valid MySQL [date literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use canonical sql date   format

```
select * from tbl_billing where date BETWEEN '2017-02-09' and '2017-02-10'
```

or convert properly using   str_to_date

```
select * from tbl_billing where date BETWEEN str_to_date('09-02-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
            and  str_to_date('10-02-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

but if also your `date` is a varchar then you must convert this column too

```
select * from tbl_billing where str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')  BETWEEN str_to_date('09-02-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
            and  str_to_date('10-02-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: hello roman thanks by advice me but the issue was my date datatype is varchar and i cant change it because i used in many pages so it cant be possible to change datatype varchar to date. if you have any solution please tell me roman sir

Comment: @phpguru Change it. Change the pages. Otherwise no 'guru'!!

Comment: @phpguru   if you have also the date column as varchar then   you must convert the column too .. answer updated ..let me know

Comment: hey Strawberry please learn php in deeply otherwise no Strawberry only lollypop, im getting that with my own login...